# Import-Module Azure Failing

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to work with Windows Azure PowerShell module on Windows 8.1. I have downloaded the Azure module.When I open PowerShell(in Admin Mode) and do Import-Module Azure it fails with following error message.

```
import-module : The specified module 'Azure.Storage' with version '2.0.1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

Comment: well, can you do install-module azure? and\or install-module azurerm? I don't exactly remember what package capabilities were there in PowerShell 4. You could also try install-package azure. If those do not work install wmf 5.0 and use those, its much easier to do it that way

Comment: I tried install-package azure,Install-module azure and nstall-package azure. All commands are giving same error (Install-module : The term 'Install-module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.)

Comment: SO you would need to upgrade to wmf 5.0+ for those to work.

Comment: Where did you download the Azure module to? It needs to be in a valid module path to be able to be imported by name. Module paths are stored in the environment variable PSModulePath, you can see this list within powershell by using the command `$Env:PSModulePath`

Comment: The module was pasted in one of the valid paths